# How to see the developer of an app?

Tags: applications

I have a Galaxy S21+ running Android 14.  In the App Info, I don't see a way to tell which apps were made by which company. I'm especially interested in the pre-installed apps. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Usually preinstalled apps are also available in Google Play or Samsung store. There you can find developer info. For play Store you only need the app packageName. Append it to the following URL: `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=` and you get to the app web page (or to the page in Play Store app).

Comment: @Robert you will be surprised how many of the preinstalled apps cannot be found in any of the "markets" – usually more than half of them… // Eric:if you don't mind starting the apps, at least some of them might have an "about" menu you could look at. // In the past, I'd have said one could look up the package signatures. But with so many developers having handed over signing to Google, nowadays that only shows "Google" for far too many apps…

Comment: @Izzy But apps that are never updated (and thus are not available in any store) are pretty rare. The only parts that are usually not updated are the system apps, but even if some of them seem to be of little use I have never seen an app that was not from the device manufacturer (but my experience is mainly about devices from major brands like Lenovo and Samsung).

Comment: @Robert you can check some example device docs from my Adebar [here](https://izzy.codeberg.page/adebar/), first look at the creation date of the report, then head to the "System Apps" secrion. Compare "first installed", "last updated", creation date.On some devices I had a hard time spotting an updated app. Follow the app links, you'll have a hard time finding one that's on Play. Most of the system apps I couldn't even find anywhere. And I remember a study that came to the exact same results: most system apps are in no store and never updated (except with ROM updates maybe).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Developer info" is not something that is usually shown inside Android OS, but mostly only related to the app store.

---

On recent Android versions, in the App Info screen, there may be a menu to see the app entry in the app store:

- Samsung: App details in store
- Pixel: App details

Selecting it should open the app directly in the store. From there, the developer of the app can be found.

---

Otherwise, as stated in [Izzy's comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/255412/how-to-see-the-developer-of-an-app#comment345273_255412), apps may provide in-app about page where the developer may also be mentioned.

Comment: Actually, [key store may contain Organization](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#generate-key), but I'm not sure how user-friendly it is to check it, or even if it's applicable for this question. Free free to expand it as a proper answer.